# Is there a tool to convert React Elements javascript code to JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

It's not difficult to find a tool to convert `JSX` to `React.createElement`, something like this:

```
  <div className="commentBox">
    Hello, world! I am a CommentBox.
  </div>
```

to this:

```
  React.createElement('div', {className: "commentBox"},
    "Hello, world! I am a CommentBox."
  )
```

I can't find a tool co make a convertation vice-versa. I have a big codebase with `React.createElement`, and I want to transform it to plain `JSX`. How can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bit of an unusual case, but there is a tool for that: https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-react-createelement-to-jsx. It seems to be relatively fresh, so good luck.

Comment: Works as expected.

Comment: I wonder if such a tool is available online as a web app.