# Tool to convert React elements js code to JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am looking to convert React Create element code to JSX.

I have found this plugin https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-react-createelement-to-jsx from this SO question 
[Is there a tool to convert React Elements javascript code to JSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36218114/is-there-a-tool-to-convert-react-elements-javascript-code-to-jsx)

Installed this babel-plugin-transform-react-createelement-to-jsx and created .babelrc file with follwing code:

```
 {
   "plugins": [ "transform-react-createelement-to-jsx" ]
 }
```

Created test.js with code:

```
"use strict";
React.createElement("div", {
    className: "commentBox"
}, "Hello, world! I am a CommentBox.");
```

I would like to know how to convert this code using this plugin and any other tool available for conversion ?

Comment: Have you tried running babel in your command line like it says in that tool? `babel --plugins transform-react-createelement-to-jsx script.js`

Comment: Tried now.It works but the file is not convering to JSX